# How to abort current request in on_body callback using Typhoeus

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I'm using Typhoeus with an hydra queue of a dozen of requests.

I'm using an on_body callback to stream the response.

What is the best way to abort the current request inside this callback (ie. reached a max file size...) without aborting all the other requests in the queue of course ?

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra

urls.each do |url|
  request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, followlocation: true, timeout: 5, connecttimeout: 5)
  request.on_body do |chunk, response|
    #
    # How to conditionally abort the request here ?
    #        
  end

  hydra.queue request
end

hydra.run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way at the moment. According to http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION it would be enough to return an invalid size. But that is not an option yet in Typhoeus since the callback itself is wrapped and it always returns the correct size: https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon/blob/master/lib/ethon/easy/callbacks.rb#L37-48.

EDIT: Ethon 0.7.1 is able to abort requests in the on_body callback: https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon/commit/6117872004c9ed1dac0ac15542dffc10177d8eae.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is that I'm using Typhoeus and a queue to crawl some URLs for which I have no control over the content. If one of these URLs is eventually a very big file I want to abort as soon as possible without continuing writing it on the disc. What would be the best way to handle that?

Comment: I would merge a change which features a special return value to abort the request. like :__abort_request. That seems to be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I released a version of Ethon which can abort requests in flight. https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon/commit/6117872004c9ed1dac0ac15542dffc10177d8eae

Answer (score 0):

According to the [README](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#streaming-the-response-body), Typhoeus now has a way to interrupt the on_body callback part-way through.

Return the `:abort` symbol:

```
request.on_body do |chunk|
  # [do stuff with the chunk]
  :abort if [some terminating condition]
end
```